# PropertyChanged for indexed property in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I found several sources explaining to use `Item[]` as the property name in the `PropertyChangedEventArgs` for an indexed property called `Item`.

But what do I have to use in VB.net? Is it `Item()` or is it `Item[]` as well?

Comment: The fact that you're writing your code in VB.NET isn't really relevant.  Just like the .NET Framework code was written in C# and you can use it in VB, so any VB code you write can be used in C# too.  You should obey the .NET standard, not different standards for VB and C#.

Comment: But indexing in C# uses square brackets while indexing in VB.net uses round brackets. That's why I'm asking whether to use `Item()` in VB.net.

Comment: I know why you're asking.  I gave you the answer.  The language you're using to write it is irrelevant because either language or even some other language may be used to consume it.

Comment: By the way, indexed properties called `Item` don't exist in C# anyway - C# uses indexers - so any advice you read about such properties WAS for VB already.

Comment: You didn't give **the** answer, **the** answer would have been "Use `Item[]`". You just gave a lengthy comment where one can assume what **the** answer might be. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Are you really just asking what the  equivalent syntax is? Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Item[]`, but note that *an indexed property called `Item`* does not make sense in a C# context.

If you want your VB.net code be consumed by C# code you should only use one indexed property in a class, make sure to add the `Default` keyword, and just return [`System.Windows.Data.Binding.IndexerName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.indexername?view=netframework-4.8):

> Used as the PropertyName of PropertyChangedEventArgs to indicate that an indexer property has changed.

(which just happens to be `Item[]`).

---

In C# you can't have named indexed properties like in VB.Net, e.g. something like

```
Default Public Property Foo(ByVal x As Integer) As Integer
   ...
End Property

Public Property Bar(ByVal x As Integer) As Integer
    ...
End Property
```

is not possible in C# (but you can have multiple indexers with different signatures).